# VBA Userform: Data update/overrides does not work properly

Tags: vba, edit, record, userform

I created a form for data entry & update.  Most of everything works except the update button.

When I clicked update, only the first argument would be updated. For example, let's say I want to update column B, C, D, E.

1) When update is clicked: Only column B got updated, everything else did not.

2) If I masked the argument for B as comment, then the cell in column C will be updated, not B, D, and E.

3) If I masked the argument for C as comment, then the cell in column D will be updated, not the rest.

Below are my code for the command Update and [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qr7XVlgqcM1yXSIUjOLIy6-NG4Y3z4EW) to current worksheet

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Ans As String
Set ws = Sheets("TEST")

If cmbSelect = "" Then
MsgBox "The Asset Number TextBox is empty, so no record can be updated in this case." & vbNewLine & _
"Please try again.....", vbExclamation, "Not Found!"
Exit Sub
End If
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Columns(1), cmbSelect) = 0 Then
MsgBox "The Asset Number you entered doesn't exist." & vbNewLine & _
      "Please try again.....", vbExclamation, "Not Found!"
Exit Sub
End If

Ans = MsgBox("Do you want to update the current record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm Please!")
If Ans = vbNo Then
MsgBox "You have cancelled the update.", vbExclamation
Exit Sub
End If

r = WorksheetFunction.Match(Val(cmbSelect), ws.Columns(1), 0)

     ws.Cells(r, "A") = Me.txtID.Text
     Cells(r, "B") = Me.txtClient.Text 'testing different formula, results are the same
     Cells(r, "C") = cmbProgram.Text
     Cells(r, "D") = Me.TextStartDate.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "E") = Me.TextEndDate.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "H") = Me.TextLocation.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "I") = Me.ComboRegion.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "F") = Me.txtMeetOrg.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "G") = Me.cmbCategory.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "H") = Me.TextLocation.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "I") = Me.ComboRegion.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "J") = Me.txtOPID.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "K") = Me.txtOPOwner.Text
     Ws.Cells(r, "L") = Me.txtStatus
     ws.Cells(r, "M") = Me.txtFName.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "N") = Me.txtPO.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "O") = Me.txtFFee.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "P") = Me.txtFETransp.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "Q") = Me.txtFEHotel.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "R") = Me.txtFEMeal.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "S") = Me.txtFEMisc.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "T") = Me.txtTotalFTE.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "U") = Me.txtTotalFE.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "V") = Me.txtIE1Name.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "W") = Me.txtIE1TE.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "X") = Me.txtIE2Name.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "Y") = Me.txtIE2TE.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "Z") = Me.txtIE3Name.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "AA") = Me.txtIE3TE.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "AD") = Me.txtParticipant.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "AE") = Me.txtResponse.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "AF") = Me.txtOverall.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "AG") = Me.txtNPS.Text
     ws.Cells(r, "AH") = Me.txtImpact.Text

MsgBox "Record has been updated successfully.", vbInformation, "Record Updated!"

 End Sub
```

Comment: For Column B, C, and D, you're missing a reference to the worksheet.

Comment: what fills cmbSelect?

Comment: cmbSelect is a combobox I can navigated to existing records with text appears as ID column (column A), but when clicked, the user can see other columns as well, which I set a different table on another tab.  Hope I answered your questions.

Comment: Hi Domenic, for column B, C, and D, I was testing with my old code, which works when I used the basic currentrow = 2.  Original reference to worksheet did not work either.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52128777/edit) to include more information.